# Qt C++, Open file without specify path or filename

Tags: c++, qt, openfiledialog

```
QString filename = "F:/tests/lineText.txt";
QFile myfile(filename);

if(!myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0,"Fail!", myfile.errorString());
    return;
}

QTextStream in(&myfile);
...
```

I want to open any TXT file, at any location, without specify filename or path. How to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you refer to a file without its filename? Please describe in more details.

Comment: vanacho is right, how can you refer to something when there is no reference?

Comment: for without hardcoding the filename you will need to get it from the user (several options for that)

Comment: I believe he intends to use it as a tempfile but I might be wrong. Even if this is what the OP means it's badly phrased...

Answer (score 2):

You are not very specific, but if I understand correctly, you actually want to be able not to hardcode the path, but to get it during runtime. You can get the path from user, using **QFileDialog** class - this will create a familiar pop-up window, allowing you to choose any file that you have privilege to open. You can also build the string representing the path and filename depending on some conditions you set, and then pass the result string to QFile.

Answer (score 1):

The only concept I can think in which that makes sense is if you want to open a `tempfile` without caring for the exact path/filename.

Maybe have a look at [QTemporaryFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtemporaryfile.html#QTemporaryFile). From the documentation:

> Constructs a QTemporaryFile in QDir::tempPath(), using the file template "qt_temp.XXXXXX". The file is stored in the system's temporary directory.